# Gradle Dokka refuses to run again

Tags: gradle, kotlin-dokka

My Project structure is a multi-module, each module has same dokka tasks

The gradle dokka plugin gives me some very strange results:

First of all it often need some artifacts of my build, like other modules.jar files, if those are not present if complains about it. From my understanding this makes not much sense as all sources are present.

Next thing i noticed is that dokka just generates docu when it likes to. That sounds a bit inaccurate as i was not able to see any rule here. When i delete my dokumentation folder, and lauch the dokka task again, dokka often does nothing.

Comment: Please provide your Gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

> Next thing i noticed is that dokka just generates docs when it likes to. (...) When i delete my dokumentation folder, and lauch the dokka task again, dokka often does nothing.

Dokka relies on Gradle to check if the task is up to date, taking into account the sources and output directory. Especially deleting dokka's output dir should ensure documentation generation. Could you please provide your project?